# How do I execute but not install a binary with autotools?

Tags: autotools, automake

I am writing a small library and want to make it accessible using autotools with automake 1.11. The only interesting outcome is the library libfoo.so.

I wrote a unit test for the library which I want be executed during the make process or when running `make check`. I don not want the unit test to appear in `$PREFIX/foo/bin/`.

How do I achieve these goals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the automake manual describes, you use the `"check_"` prefix. Let's say the library is built under the directory `src/`, and the unit tests are under `tests/` - then in the `tests/Makefile.am` file:

```
check_PROGRAMS = unit_test

unit_test_SOURCES = unit_test.c
unit_test_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libfoo.la
```

I assume you're using `libtool` of course. This takes care of linking, dynamic paths, etc., if you're building a shared library.

You should also have a look at the use of the `TESTS` variable in automake.